# Can I set a default value for Ruby's MatchData?

Tags: ruby, regex

In Hash, I can use

```
map = Hash.new("(0,0)")
```

or

```
map = Hash.new()
map.default = "(0, 0)"
```

to set a default value for undefined keys, so that when I try to retrieve value of an undefined key, I won't get an error. But in MatchData, for example, in:

```
line = "matchBegins\/blabla\" = (20, 10);"
get = line.match(/matchBegins\/(?<match1>\D*)" *= *(?<match2>.*);/)
puts get[:notExisted]
```

I will get an error. I have checked MatchData's doc, but cannot have anything for setting a default value. Am I correct? Thanks

Comment: you mean `(?P<match1>\D*)` ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ruby 2.4+ you can use 'named_captures':

```
line = "matchBegins\/blabla\" = (20, 10);"
get = line.match(/matchBegins\/(?<match1>\D*)" *= *(?<match2>.*);/)
hash = get.named_captures
```

This is a `Hash` (with stringified keys!) and you can use `fetch` to specify a default value:

```
hash.fetch('unknownKey', 'default')
```

If you are using Ruby 1.9.1+ you can use `names` and `captures` and construct a hash:

```
line = "matchBegins\/blabla\" = (20, 10);"
get = line.match(/matchBegins\/(?<match1>\D*)" *= *(?<match2>.*);/)
hash = Hash[get.names.zip(get.captures)]
```

Or just rescue the exception:

```
value = get['unknownKey'] rescue 'default'
```

(which i find ugly and code like this might mask other errors)

But, to be honest, I wonder what your use case is. Why do you need to request arbitrary keys from `MatchData`?

Comment: Vamsi Krishna, thanks for the remark about captures/zip.